# Logistic Regression on MNIST dataset

Tags: opencv, classification

In [this](https://www.simplicity.be/article/recognizing-handwritten-digits) post you can find a very good tutorial on how to apply SVM classifier to MNIST dataset. I was wondering if I could use logistic regression instead of SVM classifier. So I searhed for Logistic regression in openCV, And I found that the syntax for both classifiers are almost identical. So I guessed that I could just comment out these parts:

```
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::SVM::create();
    svm->setType(cv::ml::SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(cv::ml::SVM::POLY);//LINEAR, RBF, SIGMOID, POLY 
    svm->setTermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));
    svm->setGamma(3); 
    svm->setDegree(3);
    svm->train( trainingMat , cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE , labelsMat );
```

and replace it with:

```
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::LogisticRegression> lr1 = cv::ml::LogisticRegression::create();
    lr1->setLearningRate(0.001);
    lr1->setIterations(10);
    lr1->setRegularization(cv::ml::LogisticRegression::REG_L2);
    lr1->setTrainMethod(cv::ml::LogisticRegression::BATCH);
    lr1->setMiniBatchSize(1);
    lr1->train( trainingMat, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
```

But first I got this error: 
OpenCV Error: Bad argument(data and labels must be a floating point matrix)

Then I changed

```
cv::Mat labelsMat(labels.size(), 1, CV_32S, labelsArray);
```

to:

```
cv::Mat labelsMat(labels.size(), 1, CV_32F, labelsArray);
```

And now I get this error: OpenCV Error: bad argument(data should have atleast two classes)

I have 10 classes (0,1,...,9) but I don't know why I get this error. My codes are almost identical with the ones in the mentioned tutorial.

Comment: Probably you're interpreting your integrer values in `labelsArray` as float. Try this way and let me know: `cv::Mat labelsMat(labels.size(), 1, CV_32S, labelsArray); labelsMat.convertTo(labelsMat, CV_32F);` (the same for data)

Comment: @miki That worked well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Python you could do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.linear_models import LogisticRegression

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# The data that we are interested in is made of 8x8 images of digits, let's
# have a look at the first 3 images, stored in the `images` attribute of the
# dataset.  If we were working from image files, we could load them using
# pylab.imread.  Note that each image must have the same size. For these
# images, we know which digit they represent: it is given in the 'target' of
# the dataset.
images_and_labels = list(zip(digits.images, digits.target))
for index, (image, label) in enumerate(images_and_labels[:4]):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, index + 1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Training: %i' % label)

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
```

**Choose which one of the classifiers you like below**

```
# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# create a Logistic Regression Classifier
classifier = LogisticRegression(C=1.0)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], digits.target[:n_samples / 2])

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
expected = digits.target[n_samples / 2:]
predicted = classifier.predict(data[n_samples / 2:])

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))

images_and_predictions = list(zip(digits.images[n_samples / 2:], predicted))
for index, (image, prediction) in enumerate(images_and_predictions[:4]):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, index + 5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Prediction: %i' % prediction)

plt.show()
```

You can see the whole code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html)